# Apply IQueryable to another IQueryable / DbContext

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have an `IQueryable<Person>` which is created based on some input parameters (sort and filter).

Is possible to apply this `IQueryable<T>` to a `DbSet<T>` i have in `DbContext`?

For example:

```
// create the query from some parameters
IQueryable<Person> query = CreateQuery(parameters);

// apply the query somehow to an existing IQueryable / DbSet
AppContext db = new AppContext();
IEnumerable<Person> result = db.People.ApplyQuery(query).ToList();
```

Comment: Shouldn't `People` actually be `Person`? Are they really different types?

Comment: `db.People` is of type `DbSet<Person>`. IQuerable and DbSet have the same type

Comment: Are you able to change the `CreateQuery` method? I had a similar problem but solved it by creating a base query (`Select(x => x)`) and adding the filter and sort based on the provided `parameters` (if any).

Comment: I can change the `CreateQuery` so it receives an existing `IQuerable`, but is not elegant at all. (Also because i might not have access to the DbContext at the time of creating the query.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the context must be the same.
Even worst, I had a problem moving a ToList statement from inside a linq query to outside linq query, i.e.

```
// myQuery is an IQueryable from a different context
// This did not work
IEnumerable<Person> result = db.People.Where(p => myQuery.ToList().Contains(p.Id)).ToList();

// This worked
myList = myQuery.ToList();
IEnumerable<Person> result = db.People.Where(p => myList.Contains(p.Id)).ToList();
```

Really strange isn't it?

Comment: Ah, sorry for such a late answer :)
Yes, strange. Didn't found a solution until now, and i had to change the strategy